# MYSQL - Insert statement with syntax Error

Tags: mysql

I have following table setup.

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date        | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| limit       | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contract_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And this insert query

```
INSERT INTO userlimit (date, limit, contract_id) VALUES (now(), 10, 1);
```

Always when I want to execute it I receive following error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'limit, contract_id) VALUES (now(), 10, 1)' at line
>   1

My syntax looks perfectly fine to me. Why do I get this Error?

Comment: `LIMIT` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). When using it as a table/column name you must quote it with backticks.

Comment: Note that `date` is _not_ reserved. `limit` is though.  Requires quoting as `\`limit\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote field names with backticks

```
INSERT INTO userlimit (`date`, `limit`, `contract_id`) VALUES (now(), 10, 1)
```

Comment: Note that it is not needed for all fields, but only for the limit which ia reserved keywords.

Comment: ^^ And `date` isn't actually reserved.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, yes, only reserved words require quotes, but for uniformity I quoted all

Comment: @IbrahimApachi better late than never :)